# Rendering a T-account in HTML

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

## Example

This is a "T-account" as shown in the book *Principles of Macroeconomics* by Gregory Mankiw:

[image]

## Code

To render this, I took the approach of using nested tables:

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th>ASSETS</th> 
            <th>LIABILITIES AND OWNERS' EQUITY</th>
        </tr>
        
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Reserves</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">200</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Loans</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">700</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Securities</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">100</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>

            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Deposits</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">800</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Debt</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">150</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Capital</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">50</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

In my application (with some CSS that comes with Blazor) here's the result:

[image]

## Question

This seems to work OK, although it seems a bit odd. There's the assumption that the rows in each table will always align, for example.

Is there a better or more idiomatic way to implement the T-account in HTML?

Comment: You can post your example run using code blocks here, within your question. Do not use third party sites which might get your question closed. [ask]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Rob. I've updated the question to use snippets.

Comment: I'm talking about your jsfiddle unless that solves the issue.

Comment: @Rob, ah yes. I also removed the jsfiddle now that the snippet is used.